# Teradata SQL: Determine how many accounts had status change in given month

Tags: sql, teradata

Ok, so I have a table that looks something like this:

```
Acct_id   Eff_dt      Expr_dt      Prod_cd   Open_dt
-------------------------------------------------------
111       2012-05-01  2013-06-01   A         2012-05-01
111       2013-06-02  2014-03-08   A         2012-05-01
111       2014-03-09  9999-12-31   B         2012-05-01
222       2015-07-15  2015-11-11   A         2015-07-15
222       2015-11-12  2016-08-08   B         2015-07-15
222       2016-08-09  9999-12-31   A         2015-07-15
333       2016-01-01  2016-04-15   B         2016-01-01
333       2016-04-16  2016-08-08   B         2016-01-01
333       2016-08-09  9999-12-31   A         2016-01-01
444       2017-02-03  2017-05-15   A         2017-02-03
444       2017-05-16  2017-12-02   A         2017-02-03
444       2017-12-03  9999-12-31   B         2017-02-03
555       2017-12-12  9999-12-31   B         2017-12-12
```

There are many more columns that I'm not including as they're otherwise not relevant.

What I'm trying to determine is how many accounts had a change in `Prod_cd` in a given month, but then only in one direction (so from A > B in this example).  Sometimes however an account was first opened as B, and then later changed to A.  Or it was opened as A, changed to B, and moved back to A.  I only want to know the current set of accounts where in a given month the `Prod_cd` changed from A to B.

`Eff_dt` is the date when a change was made to an account (could be any change, such as address change,  name change, or what I'm looking for, product code change).

`Expr_dt` is the expiration date of that row, essentially the last day before a new change was made.  When the date of that row is 9999-12-31, that's the most current row.

`Open_dt` is the date the account was created.

I created a query at first that was something like this:

```
select
   count(distinct acct_id)

from table

where prod_cd = 'B'
and expr_dt = '9999-12-31'
and eff_dt between '2017-12-01' and '2017-12-31'
and open_dt < '2017-12-01'
```

But it's giving me results that don't look right.  I want to specifically track the # of conversions that happened, but the count of accounts I'm getting seems way too high.

There is probably a way to create a more reliable query using window functions, but given that the `Prod_cd` changes can happen in multiple directions, I'm not sure how to write that query.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What about A --> B --> C?  What about B --> A --> C --> B?  Do these count?

Comment: Could you provide the create and insert statements so its easier for us to play around with the query and help you get a better answer?

Comment: Yeah, there are more product codes than just A and B, but in this table you wouldn't see changes from A > C for example, as any other product codes are just different account types altogether (would also have a different format for the Acct_id).  So conversions would only happen between A and B.

Comment: What about A-B-A, does this count? Which accounts in your example date should match?

Comment: Please do not add the solution to your question, instead you can either select one from the answers below or answer your question yourself.

Comment: Added the final query up top, with thanks to @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are specifically looking for the switch A --> B, then the simplest method is to use `lag()`.  But, Teradata requires a slightly different formulation:

```
select count(distinct acct_id)
from (select t.*,
             max(prod_cd) over (partition by acct_id order by effdt rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_prod_cd
      from t
     ) t
where prod_cd = 'B' and prev_prod_cd = 'A' and
      expr_dt = '9999-12-31' and
      eff_dt between '2017-12-01' and '2017-12-31' and
      open_dt < '2017-12-01';
```

I am guessing that the date conditions go in the outer query -- meaning that they `lag()` does not use them.

Comment: I just tried this approach but I get an error "Data Type "prod_cd" does not match a Defined Type name."  Hmmm, need to troubleshoot that.

Comment: Does lag() only work when the data types are sequential in nature (i.e. B follows after A)?  The actual product codes in the table are F1 and F3.

Comment: i don't think Teradata supports `lag`.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala That would make sense.  I'll modify this to use "rows preceding"

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala . . . I always forget that.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Gordon's answer, but using a supported window function (instead of LAG) and using Teradata's QUALIFY clause to do the lag-gy lookup:

```
SELECT DISTINCT acct_id
FROM mytable    
QUALIFY 
    MAX(prod_cd) OVER (PARTITION BY acct_id ORDER BY eff_dt ASC ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) = 'A'
    AND prod_cd = 'B'
    AND expr_dt = '9999-12-31'
    AND eff_dt between DATE '2013-01-01' and DATE '2017-12-31'
    AND open_dt < DATE '2017-12-01'
```

Comment: Thanks.  Both your answer and Gordon's answer give me the same result.

Comment: Yep! They are almost 100% identical. The only difference is moving the subquery (which is they way you would do this in any other RDBMS) into Teradata's [QUALIFY clause](https://info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1146-160K/fwv1472240802570.html), which is a Teradata-only expansion to the ANSI SQL standard. It can be thought of as analogous to the HAVING clause, but for window functions.